# is it possible to access local file from file system using Okhttp

Tags: java, android, okhttp

I have cordova webview in that one i'm loading the html from the filesystem i want to intercept the request using OkHttpClient is there any way i can request file from filesystem using OkHttpClient.

i tried to do normal call with okhttp but its giving error

```
Expected URL scheme 'http' or 'https' but was 'file'
```

```
    WebResourceResponse getRequestResponse(String url) {
    try {
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
        final Call call = okHttpClient.newCall(new 
        Request.Builder().url(url).build());

        final Response response = call.execute();

        return new 
         WebResourceResponse("","",response.body().byteStream());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
    }
```

Comment: wait ... you  want to get a local file on the machine on which you are executing a web app (as client, not as server)?

Comment: yes the webview is loading html file and in that file some resources are linked so when webview is trying to get that one it isn't picking correct location so i want to modify that request url with new url.

Comment: you do understand that would be a very - serious security breach? a website that can access your local files without any interaction of you?

Comment: that won't be its local file in android device and that part of the code is only executed when the internet is not there

Comment: It's like opening a html file in browser from the local computer

Comment: it's a file your app creates on the device?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197873/discussion-between-nikul-vadher-and-stultuske).

Answer (score 1):

Use a magic hostname like "filesystem.local" and get an interceptor to handle requests to this host by loading from the filesystem.

```
val url = "http://filesystem.local/path/to/file.png".toHttpUrl()
```

Comment: i tried but not working in android getting ```Unable to resolve host "filesystem.local": No address associated with hostname```

Comment: @NikulVadher You need to also make an interceptor that will intercept urls with `filesystem.local` "magic" hostname and go into the filesystem instead of over the internet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use such an interceptor where you pass the url to `rewrittenIfFileSchemeUrl(…)` and use its return value as the actual url for the OkHttp request:

```kotlin
import okhttp3.Interceptor
import okhttp3.Protocol
import okhttp3.Response
import okhttp3.ResponseBody.Companion.toResponseBody
import java.io.FileNotFoundException
import java.net.URL

internal object OkHttpFileUrlHandler : Interceptor {

    fun rewrittenIfFileSchemeUrl(url: String): String {
        return if (url.startsWith("file:")) {
            url.replaceFirst("file:", fileSystemMarkerPrefix)
        } else url
    }

    private const val fileSystemMarkerHost = "filesystem.local"
    private const val fileSystemMarkerPrefix = "http://$fileSystemMarkerHost"

    private fun restoreFileUrl(markedFakeHttpUrl: String): String {
        return markedFakeHttpUrl.replaceFirst(fileSystemMarkerPrefix, "file:")
    }

    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val request = chain.request()
        val url = request.url
        if (url.host != fileSystemMarkerHost) return chain.proceed(request)
        val fileUrl = restoreFileUrl(url.toString())
        return try {
            Response.Builder()
                .body(URL(fileUrl).readBytes().toResponseBody())
                .code(200)
                .message("Some file")
                .protocol(Protocol.HTTP_1_0)
                .request(request)
                .build()
        } catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
            Response.Builder()
                .body("".toResponseBody())
                .code(404)
                .message(e.message ?: "File not found ($fileUrl)")
                .protocol(Protocol.HTTP_1_0)
                .request(request)
                .build()
        }
    }
}
```